# Query on Booleans in Lambda Calculus

Tags: functional-programming, lambda-calculus

This is the lambda calculus representation for the AND operator:

```
lambda(m).lambda(n).lambda (a).lambda (b). m(n a b) b
```

Can anyone help me in understanding this representation?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To understand how to represent Booleans in lambda calculus, it helps to think about an IF expression, "if a then b else c". This is an expression which chooses the first branch, b, if it is true, and the second, c, if it is false. Lambda expressions can do that very easily:

```
lambda(x).lambda(y).x
```

will give you the first of its arguments, and

```
lambda(x).lambda(y).y
```

gives you the second. So if a is one of those expressions, then

```
a b c
```

gives either `b` or `c`, which is just what we want the IF to do. So define

```
 true = lambda(x).lambda(y).x
false = lambda(x).lambda(y).y
```

and `a b c` will behave like `if a then b else c`.

Looking inside your expression at `(n a b)`, that means `if n then a else b`.
Then `m (n a b) b` means

```
if m then (if n then a else b) else b
```

This expression evaluates to `a` if both `m` and `n` are `true`, and to `b` otherwise. Since `a` is the first argument of your function and `b` is the second, and `true` has been defined as a function that gives the first of its two arguments, then if `m` and `n` are both `true`, so is the whole expression. Otherwise it is `false`. And that's just the definition of `and`!

All this was invented by Alonzo Church, who invented the lambda calculus.

Comment: Thank you so very much !!! I am finding Lambda Calculus really difficult to understand and such explanations make my life a lot easier !! Thank you again.

Comment: @Peter: Just another help needed, if you can: I am reading Church Booleans on wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_encoding#Church_booleans

I am not able to understand how the examples are inferred i.e. AND TRUE FALSE.

Can you help me understand them?

Comment: The way to understand those long expressions is just to remember the rules and evaluate them one step at a time, left to right. So in the expression `(λm.λn. m n m) (λa.λb. a) (λa.λb. b)`
the first part in parentheses is a function, and the second and third parts get substituted for m and n:`(λa.λb. a) (λa.λb. b) (λa.λb. a)`. Then do the same thing again, remembering that the a and b in each parenthesis are completely independent of each other. The first part, `(λa.λb. a)`, returns the first of its two arguments. So it returns `(λa.λb. b)`, which is the Church representation of false.

Comment: Great Peter !!! Thank you very much. Did you learn Lambda Calculus in school or you read any documentation to get this level of understanding?

Also, another question I have is:

(lambda (a) (lambda (b) ((lambda (c) c) b)))

In this case, is the outer 'c' of "(lambda (c) c)" a free variable or a bounded variable ??

Comment: I think I first saw lambdas in a book on Lisp, then a book on Denotational Semantics. I don't recall where Booleans came into it, but I did have great fun reconstructing how they worked after I had forgotten! Enjoying it is the secret to understanding it. For your question, the outer "c" is bound, because it's named in the "lambda (c)" part.

Comment: Woww !! That's really great that you still remember ... Thanks a lot for your help Peter !!

Answer (score 8):

In the lambda calculus, a Boolean is represented by a function that takes two arguments, one for success and one for failure.  The arguments are called *continuations*, because they continue with the rest of the computation; the boolean True calls the success continuation and the Boolean False calls the failure continuation.  This coding is called the Church encoding, and the idea is that a Boolean is very much like an "if-then-else function".

So we can say

```
true  = \s.\f.s
false = \s.\f.f
```

where `s` stands for success, `f` stands for failure, and the backslash is an ASCII lambda.

Now I hope you can see where this is going.   How do we code `and`?  Well, in C we could expand it to

```
n && m = n ? m : false
```

Only these are functions, so

```
(n && m) s f = (n ? m : false) s f = n ? (m s f) : (false s f) = n ? (m s f) : f
```

BUT, the ternary construct, when coded in the lambda calculus, is just function application, so we have

```
(n && m) s f = (n m false) s f = n (m s f) (false s f) = n (m s f) f
```

So finally we arrive at

```
&& = \n . \m . \s . \f . n (m s f) f
```

And if we rename the success and failure continuations to `a` and `b` we return to your original

```
&& = \n . \m . \a . \b . n (m a b) b
```

As with other computations in lambda calculus, especially when using Church encodings, **it is often easier to work things out with algebraic laws** and equational reasoning, then convert to lambdas at the end.

Answer (score 4):

Actually it's a little more than just the AND operator. It's the lambda calculus' version of `if m and n then a else b`. Here's the explanation:

In lambda calculus true is represented as a function taking two arguments* and returning the first. False is represented as function taking two arguments* and returning the second.

The function you showed above takes four arguments*. From the looks of it m and n are supposed to be booleans and a and b some other values. If m is true, it will evaluate to its first argument which is `n a b`. This in turn will evaluate to a if n is true and b if n is false. If m is false, it will evaluate to its second argument b.

So basically the function returns a if both m and n are true and b otherwise.

(*) Where "taking two arguments" means "taking an argument and returning a function taking another argument".

Edit in response to your comment:

`and true false` as seen on the wiki page works like this:

The first step is simply to replace each identifier with its definition, i.e. `(λm.λn. m n m) (λa.λb. a) (λa.λb. b)`. Now the function `(λm.λn. m n m)` is applied. This means that every occurrence of m in `m n m` is replaced with the first argument (`(λa.λb. a)`) and every occurrence of n is replaced with the second argument (`(λa.λb. b)`). So we get `(λa.λb. a) (λa.λb. b) (λa.λb. a)`. Now we simply apply the function `(λa.λb. a)`. Since the body of this function is simply a, i.e. the first argument, this evaluates to `(λa.λb. b)`, i.e. `false` (as `λx.λy. y` means `false`).

Comment: @sepp: Can you help me out, if you can with the 2nd comment posted by me below to Peter?