# Why is cond a special form in Scheme, rather than a function?

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, programming-languages, racket

```
(defun triangle-using-cond (number)
  (cond 
    ((<= number 0) 0) ; 1st
    ((= number 1) 1)  ; 2nd
    ((> number 1)     ; 3rd
      ;; 4th
      (+ number
         (triangle-using-cond (1- number))))))
```

**Things that I know about Cond**

- It allows multiple test and alternative expressions
- It has pre-specified evaluation order. For instance, the first condition will always evaluated whether it is right or not

One thing that I cannot distinguish is that what makes cond different from a function!

Comment: Your example is in Common Lisp, not Scheme nor Racket. Your question still stands though.

Comment: This is about `if`, but is correct for `cond` as well: http://vepa.in/technology/why-is-if-a-special-form-in-scheme

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A function call `(e0 e1 e2)` is evaluated like this

```
1. e0 is evaluated, the result is (hopefully) a function f
2. e1 is evaluated, the result is a value v1
3. e2 is evaluated, the result is a value v2
4. The function body of `f` is evaluated in an environment in which
   the formal parameters are bound to the values `v1` and `v2`.
```

Note that all expressions `e0`, `e1`, and, `e2` are evaluated before the body of the function is activated.

This means that a function call like  `(foo #t 2 (/ 3 0))` will result in an error when `(/ 3 0)` is evaluated - before control is handed over to the body of `foo`.

Now consider the special form `if`. In `(if #t 2 (/ 3 0))` the expressions `#t` is evaluated and since the value non-false, the second expression `2` is evaluated and the resulting value is 2. Here `(/ 3 0)` is never evaluated.

If in contrast `if` were a function, then the expressions `#t`, `2`, and, `(/ 3 0)` are evaluated before the body of is activated. And now `(/ 3 0)` will produce an error - even though the value of that expressions is not needed.

In short: Function calls will always evaluate all arguments, before the control is passed to the function body. If some expressions are not to be evaluated a special form is needed.

Here `if` and `cond` are examples of forms, that don't evaluate all subexpressions - so they they need to be special forms.

Comment: Note: Racket require left-to-right evaluation of function arguments - in R5RS the order is unspecified.

Answer (score 5):

If `cond` were not a special form then the expression:

```
((> number 1)         ;;3rd
 (+ number (triangle-using-cond (1- number))))
```

would cause either:

- an infinite loop because `triangle-using-cond` would keep calling itself recursively via the tail call  `(triangle-using-cond (1- number))`.
- or, the last expression would try to apply the value `#f` or `#t` as a function (which in a type-2 Lisp such as ANSI Common Lisp is possible, but not possible in a type-1 Lisp such as Racket or Scheme) and produce an error.

What makes `cond` a special form is that its arguments are evaluated lazily whereas functions in Scheme or Common Lisp evaluate their arguments eagerly.

Comment: Thank you guys for adding your great responses.

Comment: @ben I've never heard the terms "type-1/type-2" Lisp. Could you elaborate on that? (Just curious what the distinction means.)

Comment: @phg Typically symbols in lisps map to values. Values can be conventional datatypes as well as functions. The \1\ in "lisp-1" describes a lisp with a single name space where the symbol `foo` can map to exactly one value of any type. The \2\ in "lisp-2" describes a lisp with two namespaces, one for "conventional" data-types and the other for functions. ANSI Common Lisp is a lisp-2 and so the symbol `foo` can map to an integer value in one namespace and to a function/procedure value in the second namespace. It will evaluate to one or the other based on it's position within the expression.

Comment: Ah, ok, that's something I'm familiar with, although I've never heard it being called like this. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

As already answered, all arguments to a call to some function *f* are evaluated before the result of applying *f* is computed. Does it however mean that `cond`, or `if`, or both should be special forms?

Well, first, if you have `if`, you can easily simulate a `cond` with nested tests. Conversely, `if` is just a degenerate form of `cond`. So you can say that it is sufficient to have one of them a special form. Let's choose `if` because it is simpler to specify.

So shall `if` be special?

#### It doesn't really need to...

If the underlying question is *"is `if` expressible in terms of a smaller set of special forms?"*, then the answers is *yes*: just implement `if` [in terms of functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2398503/query-on-booleans-in-lambda-calculus):

```
(define true-fn (lambda (then else) (then)))
(define false-fn (lambda (then else) (else)))
```

Whenever you can return a boolean, you return one of the above function instead.
You could for example decide to bind `#t` and `#f` to those functions.
Notice how they *call* one of the two input parameters.

```
((pair? x) ;; returns either true-fn or false-fn 
  (lambda () (+ x 1))
  (lambda () x))
```

#### ...but why code in lambda calculus?

Evaluating code conditionally is really a fundamental operation of computing. Trying to find a  minimal special forms where you cannot express that directly leads to a *poorer* programming language from the perspective of the programmer, however "clean" the core language is.

*From a certain point of view*, the `if` form (or `cond`) is *necessary* because without them it becomes really hard to express conditional execution in a way that a compiler/interpreter can handle efficiently.

[This document](http://vepa.in/technology/why-is-if-a-special-form-in-scheme) referenced by [uselpa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33465692/why-is-cond-a-special-form-in-scheme-rather-than-a-function#comment54717488_33465692) discuss using closures to implement `if`, and concludes:

> However, the syntactic inconvenience would be so great that even
>   Scheme defines if as a special form.

Comment: Thank you guys for adding your great responses.